# Как проверить является ли XML файл пустым? Язык C#

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Для сериализации и десериализации использую XmlSerializer. При запуске программа должна считать определенную информацию, но если файл с которого она считывает является пустым, то выполнение останавливается. Что нужно: проверить является ли файл пустым и если он не пустой то считать информацию.

Вот мои методы для записи и считывания информации:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Serialize all clients to xml file 
        /// </summary>
        public void WriteToXml()
        {
            // Formatter for List<Clients>
            XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Client>));

            // Stream wich will write all data to file DataClients.xml
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataClients.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, Clients);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize all clients to List<Clients> when programm start
        /// </summary>
        public void WriteFromXml()
        {
            // Formatter for List<Clients>
            XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Client>));

            // All clients will deserialize from "DataClients.xml" to Clients.
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataClients.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                Clients = (List<Client>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Нужно обернуть код в `try-catch`. Это убережёт и от пустого файла и от повреждённого файла и от всяческих прочих сбоев.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov проще, да, но хорошо ли использовать исключения для реализации логики приложения? Особенно если есть другой способ. Штатные ситуации можно и нормальными способами обработать, а исключения - как раз для всего остального (отвалился диск во время чтения/записи, файл занят другим процессом и т.д.).

Comment: @aepot - Вот именно, что перехват исключений позволит обработать все эти ситуации. У автора этого нет, вот пусть и учится все возможные ошибки обрабатывать.

Comment: Кажется, что наилучшим вариантом будет проверка XML-файла на соответствие XSD-схеме.

Comment: Кстати, если вы не используете древний фреймворк, а используете .NET Core или .NET 5, и у вас нет четкого требования использовать именно XML, то я рекомендую использовать JSON с помощью серализатора `System.Text.Json`. С ним и работать проще, и памяти меньше кушает (в ~3 раза), и сам файл проще читать визуально. Так же этот JSON серализатор имеет асинхронное API, в случае, если файл большой или данные ползут из сети или туда отправляются. Асинхронность избавит ваше приложения от подвисаний во время выполнения операции.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал просто обернуть код в try/catch, и ловить исключения.

В случае, если файл пустой, или файла нет, или у вас нет прав на доступ к файлу, или файл оказался каталогом, или в файле невалидный XML, или удалённая файловая система отвалилась по сетевому таймауту, или... (ad nauseam) вы получите исключение, которое вам нужно будет правильно проинтерпретировать.

Предварительные проверки не спасают полностью, т. к. [приведут к race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use): вы не контролируете файл, а значит, не можете рассчитывать, что процесс чтения не взбрыкнёт в самый последний момент. Файл может оказаться пустым сразу после всех ваших проверок.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Eric Lippert, *Vexing exceptions*](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: Пардон, что не по теме, но вы все-таки вернулись на стек?)

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev: Как говорила Мэри Поппинс, «останусь, пока ветер не переменится». Я ненадолго. Но спасибо, что помните.